# Preserving cursor position with angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, validation

The following snippet does what I want to an `input`, i.e., it removes all non-alphanumerical characters, converts to uppercase, and preserves the cursor position.

```
element = $(element);

element.keyup(function() {
    var x = element.val();
    var y = x && x.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z\d]/g, '');
    if (x===y) return;
    var start = this.selectionStart;
    var end = this.selectionEnd + y.length - x.length;
    element.val(y);
    this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
});
```

I placed this snippet in the `link` of a directive and it works.... mostly.

The problem is that the `angular` model sees the value *before* the change gets applied. I tried to Google for how to use `$apply` or `$digest` or whatever here, but nothing worked.

(Actually, I somehow managed it, but then the content was re-rendered and I lost the position. I can't reproduce it, but it wasn't good enough, anyway.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A way of doing this where

- The input is only cleaned once
- `ngChange` on the input is then only fired once

is to use the `$parsers` array that the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) provides. It's designed as a place to affect the model value (via its return value), but it also can be used as a listener to input events.

```
app.directive('cleanInput', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
      var el = element[0];

      function clean(x) {
        return x && x.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z\d]/g, '');
      }

      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        var cleaned = clean(val);

        // Avoid infinite loop of $setViewValue <-> $parsers
        if (cleaned === val) return val;

        var start = el.selectionStart;
        var end = el.selectionEnd + cleaned.length - val.length;

        // element.val(cleaned) does not behave with
        // repeated invalid elements
        ngModelController.$setViewValue(cleaned);
        ngModelController.$render();

        el.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        return cleaned;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

However, I'm not sure if this usage of `$parsers` is a bit of a hack. The directive can be used as:

```
<input type="text" clean-input ng-model="name">
```

or if you would like an `ngChange` function:

```
<input type="text" clean-input ng-model="name" ng-change="onChange()">
```

This can be seen in-action at http://plnkr.co/edit/dAJ46XmmC49wqTgdp2qz?p=preview

Comment: great solution, thanks! all the other ways I tried to set the caret position caused the caret jumping back and forth, and your solution works just perfect

Comment: @michal-charemza It is possible to maintain different modelValue and viewValue. For example, I want to format input on the fly like XXX-XXX-XXXX but the model should contains XXXXXXXXXX only.

Answer (score 1):

The main things that are needed are:

- Require `ngModelController` to be able to call its methods and get/set its values. Specifically...
- Replace the call `element.val(y)` with

  ```
  ngModelController.$setViewValue(y);
  ngModelController.$render();
  ```

  I think the I should admit, I'm not entirely sure on the inner workings of `ngModelController` to understand why this is necessary.
- Optional, but getting the existing value in the view by `element.val()` can be instead done by:

  ```
  ngModelController.$viewValue;
  ```

  which is at least a more consistent with the way of setting the view value.
- Again optional, but listening to the `input` event makes the interface a bit nicer, as it seems to fire a bit before the `keyup` event, so you don't get a flash of the unprocessed input.
- Adding to the `$parsers` array to process the input seems to stop any `ngChange` callbacks being fired for the un-processed version of the input.

  ```
  ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(val) {
    // Return the processed value
  })
  ```

Putting all this together as a custom directive:

```
app.directive('cleanInput', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
      function clean(x) {
        return x && x.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z\d]/g, '');
      }

      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        return clean(val);
      })

      element.on('input', function() {
        var x = ngModelController.$viewValue;
        var y = clean(x);

        var start = this.selectionStart;
        var end = this.selectionEnd + y.length - x.length;

        ngModelController.$setViewValue(y);
        ngModelController.$render();
        this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

which can be used as:

```
<input type="text" clean-input ng-model="name">
```

or if you would like an `ngChange` function:

```
<input type="text" clean-input ng-model="name ng-change="onChange()">
```

and seen in action at http://plnkr.co/edit/FymZ8QEKwj2xXTmaExrH?p=preview

Edit: add the part about `$parsers` array. I should admit, it was @Engineer's answer that made me think of it.

Comment: This seems to work fine, it just doesn't feel right: I need to clean it twice, once in `oninput` and once in `$parsers`.

Comment: I agree about not feeling right. Trying to convince myself/yourself that it's ok, I realised ngModelController controls/interacts with 2 things. The model value, and the view value. So then cleaning input once for each could be seen as ok. However, I have now thought of an alternative where it's cleaned once, but not sure if it's a bit of a back. Will post as a separate answer.