# When to set caret position in $parser method of angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `ngModelController` for formatting using `input` element. But I'm unable to set the caret position, if the user tries to enter any digit in the beginning or in the middle. As the caret alway jumps at the end.

What is the best place for calling set cursor?

```
ngModelController.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/ /g, '');
                // $log.info(`viewValue = ${viewValue}`);
                console.log(`$modelValue = ${ngModelController.$modelValue} | $viewValue = ${ngModelController.$viewValue}`);
                console.log(`cursorPos = ${cursor.getCursorPos(elem[0])}`);
                var newVal = ""
                for (var i = 0; i < plainNumber.length; i++) {
                    if (i === 3 || i === 6) {
                        newVal += " ";
                    }
                    newVal += plainNumber[i];
                }

                cursor.setCursorPos(cursor.getCursorPos(elem[0]) + 1, elem[0]);

                // $log.info(`newVal = ${newVal}`);
                elem.val(newVal);
                return plainNumber;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

similar question:

[Preserving cursor position with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940346/preserving-cursor-position-with-angularjs)

But I've added the below code, may be useful to other.

```
    ngModelController.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
        var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/ /g, '');
        // $log.info(`viewValue = ${viewValue}`);
        console.log(`$modelValue = ${ngModelController.$modelValue} | $viewValue = ${ngModelController.$viewValue} | viewValue = ${viewValue} | cursorPos = ${cursor.getCursorPos(elem[0])} | oldVal = ${oldVal}`);
        var newVal = ""
        for (var i = 0; i < plainNumber.length; i++) {
            if (i === 3 || i === 6) {
                newVal += " ";
            }
            newVal += plainNumber[i];
        }

        if(newVal === viewValue) {
            return viewValue;
        }

        // $log.info(`newVal = ${newVal}`);
        var lastCursorPos = cursor.getCursorPos(elem[0]);
        elem.val(newVal);
        ngModelController.$setViewValue(newVal);
        ngModelController.$render();

        //cursor.setCursorPos(cursor.getCursorPos(elem[0]) + 1, elem[0]);
        elem[0].setSelectionRange(lastCursorPos + 1, lastCursorPos + 1);
        oldVal = newVal;

        return plainNumber;
    });
```