# Cursor goes to end of input when changing data in safari broswer

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

The cursor goes to the end of input when changing data in the safari browser. all other browsers working fine, but safari browser this problem happened. this code write it angular 7.
user.component.ts

```
<panel-input-box
    [width]="'100%'"
    [inputType]="inputTypes.text"
    [labelWebtext]="'ButtonText'"
    [labelFallback]="'Button text'"
    [placeholderWebtext]="'EnterButtonName'"
    [placeholderFallback]="'Enter button name'"
    [showCheckbox]="true"
    [(value)]="snoopstarButton.name"
    [isChecked]="snoopstarButton.hasButtonText"
    [showRedBorder] = "requiredFields.nameRequired"
    (checkboxClicked)="toggleCheckBox(targetButtonKeys.hasButtonText);"
    (onBlur)="updateStoreAndAutosave(targetButtonKeys.name, $event);confirmationForCreateButton()"
    [checkboxTestId]="'has-btn-text'"
    [inputTestId]="'btn-name'"
  </panel-input-box>
```

Comment: I found a similar question here. This might help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192442/cursor-goes-to-end-of-input-when-changing-data